# Deserialize gRPC-Web request

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have byte array
`[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xf2, 0x3e, 0x00]`
This array sending in socket with gRPC-Web protocol.
Additional information about request:

```
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/grpc-web+proto
Content-Length: 8
x-grpc-web: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.12.12
```

Proto file that I have:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package Device;

option go_package = "api/device";

import "api/common/status/status.proto";
import "api/device/command.proto";
import "api/device/common.proto";
import "api/device/dish.proto";
import "api/device/transceiver.proto";
import "api/device/wifi.proto";

message ToDevice {
    oneof message {
        Device.Request request = 1 [json_name="request"];
    }
}

message FromDevice {
    oneof message {
        Device.Response response = 1 [json_name="response"];
        Device.Event event = 2 [json_name="event"];
    }
}

message Request {
    optional uint64 id = 1 [json_name="id"];
    optional uint64 epoch_id = 14 [json_name="epochId"];
    optional string target_id = 13 [json_name="targetId"];
    oneof request {
        Device.SignedData signed_request = 15 [json_name="signedRequest"];
        Device.GetNextIdRequest get_next_id = 1006 [json_name="getNextId"];
        Device.AuthenticateRequest authenticate = 1005 [json_name="authenticate"];
        Device.EnableFlowRequest enable_flow = 1018 [json_name="enableFlow"];
        Device.FactoryResetRequest factory_reset = 1011 [json_name="factoryReset"];
        Device.GetDeviceInfoRequest get_device_info = 1008 [json_name="getDeviceInfo"];
        Device.GetHistoryRequest get_history = 1007 [json_name="getHistory"];
        Device.GetLogRequest get_log = 1012 [json_name="getLog"];
        Device.GetNetworkInterfacesRequest get_network_interfaces = 1015 [json_name="getNetworkInterfaces"];
        Device.GetPingRequest get_ping = 1009 [json_name="getPing"];
        Device.PingHostRequest ping_host = 1016 [json_name="pingHost"];
        Device.GetStatusRequest get_status = 1004 [json_name="getStatus"];
        Device.RebootRequest reboot = 1001 [json_name="reboot"];
        Device.SetSkuRequest set_sku = 1013 [json_name="setSku"];
        Device.SetTrustedKeysRequest set_trusted_keys = 1010 [json_name="setTrustedKeys"];
        Device.SpeedTestRequest speed_test = 1003 [json_name="speedTest"];
        Device.UpdateRequest update = 1014 [json_name="update"];
        Device.GetLocationRequest get_location = 1017 [json_name="getLocation"];
        Device.GetHeapDumpRequest get_heap_dump = 1019 [json_name="getHeapDump"];
        Device.RestartControlRequest restart_control = 1020 [json_name="restartControl"];
        Device.FuseRequest fuse = 1021 [json_name="fuse"];
        Device.DishStowRequest dish_stow = 2002 [json_name="dishStow"];
        Device.DishGetContextRequest dish_get_context = 2003 [json_name="dishGetContext"];
        Device.DishGetObstructionMapRequest dish_get_obstruction_map = 2008 [json_name="dishGetObstructionMap"];
        Device.DishEmcRequest dish_emc = 2007 [json_name="dishEmc"];
        Device.TransceiverIFLoopbackTestRequest transceiver_if_loopback_test = 4001 [json_name="transceiverIfLoopbackTest"];
        Device.TransceiverGetStatusRequest transceiver_get_status = 4003 [json_name="transceiverGetStatus"];
        Device.TransceiverGetTelemetryRequest transceiver_get_telemetry = 4004 [json_name="transceiverGetTelemetry"];
        Device.WifiGetClientsRequest wifi_get_clients = 3002 [json_name="wifiGetClients"];
        Device.WifiGetDiagnosticsRequest wifi_get_diagnostics = 3008 [json_name="wifiGetDiagnostics"];
        Device.WifiGetPingMetricsRequest wifi_get_ping_metrics = 3007 [json_name="wifiGetPingMetrics"];
        Device.WifiSetConfigRequest wifi_set_config = 3001 [json_name="wifiSetConfig"];
        Device.WifiGetConfigRequest wifi_get_config = 3009 [json_name="wifiGetConfig"];
        Device.WifiSetupRequest wifi_setup = 3003 [json_name="wifiSetup"];
    }
}
```

It is a part of file, where requests defines. Maybe it helps. That file gets from device.

How to desialize this array to get data that sending with socket. Protobuf file are present

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add the proto to your question. It's possible that the byte array you're receiving is a proto `bytes`. The `bytes` [type](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#scalar) is used for binary content.

Comment: Update a question.

Comment: @DazWilkin i have a programm, that:
first - connect to device with socket
second - send POST request
third - send byte array
fourth - function running on device and get response
i want to know, what sending with this byte array and is that possible that byte array requested to memory address on device?
For example that array [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xf2, 0x3e, 0x00] call getNextId function. In proto it is  Device.GetNextIdRequest get_next_id = 1006 [json_name="getNextId"];

Comment: Thanks for adding the proto. I apologize but I still don't understand your question and I'm unable to guess what you mean. You're using gRPC-Web so that you can use JavaScript (through a proxy) to POST messages to the proxy to a gRPC service. One of the `Request` message bodies is `GetNextIdRequest`. You don't include the definition for `GetNextIdRequest` but I assume it's a message containing a field of type `bytes`? Perhaps `repeated int32`?

Comment: You may want to follow the [style guide](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/style/) for Protos. Package names should be lowercase i.e. `package device`. It's possible but unconventional to prefix messages within a package by their package name, so consider using e.g. `Request request = 1` rather than `Device.Request Request = 1`. In Go, for example the name of the oneof e.g. `oneof request`, becomes part of the generated types (`Request`) and so you'd have some complexity in `Request.Request.GetNextIdRequest`.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for your reply. It is a part of proto file. My question is "Can i deserialize or do other operations with byte array to get readable data from it?". I try functions in c++ and python but can't get result that show me text or string data.

Comment: Yes, you will be able to do so **but** you'll need to know what the binary data represents and this isn't represented by the proto schema. If, as you say, the proto schema defines the field as `bytes` then the encoding of those bytes is by the app not by Protobuf and so you'd need to understand the programmer's intent

Comment: @DazWilkin, so, that array can request memory address on the device? Or run function that stored in memory?

Comment: Apologies, this question has taken too much of my time and I'm still unclear about your problem. Good luck!

Comment: @kdvb Hi there! I wonder if you've seen this [thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/634#issuecomment-535242751) which explains how to decode grpc-web responses per this [spec](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-WEB.md)? There's also an [Chrome plugin](https://github.com/iendeavor/grpc-devtools) you could use to help with decoding, if that helps.